# Research papers on improving speaking fluency?

Tags: reference-request, speaking

I'm currently looking for scholarly research papers that discuss how speaking fluency is developed, especially for people learning English.

If there are any recommended readings, please share them here.

I'm interested in reading about scientific findings.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does "English learners" here refer to people learning English, or English people learning other languages? (There is probably a ton of research on speaking fluency.)

Comment: English learners refer to people learning English :)

Comment: Like @ChristopheStrobbe mentioned, there is no doubt quite a bit of research on this topic, so I'm sure you'll get an answer soon.

Comment: Folks, take a look at the [Resources for Researching Language Learning Questions](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/440/800) to help you answer this question.

Answer (score 5):

Here are several references to get you started:

1. [How Long Does It Take English Learners To Attain Proficiency?](https://eric.ed.gov/?ID=ED443275)
2. [Investigating Fluency in EFL: A Quantitative Approach](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-1770.1990.tb00669.x)
3. [Oral Skill Development in Second Languages (link to PDF)](http://www.academypublication.com/ojs/index.php/tpls/article/download/tpls050917631770/383)